How can I use v-img with SVG images?
I'm using Vuetify v-img tag, but it doesn't seem to accept SVG images.
<!-- does not work -->
<v-img src="../assets/logo.svg" width="40"></v-img>

So I tried the classic img tag and it works.
<img src="../assets/logo.svg" width="40" />

What am I doing wrong? Do I need some kind of specific configuration before being able to use SVG images with Vuetify?
Edit #1
Thanks to @umur insights I was able to make it work.
<script setup langs="ts">
import logo from '../assets/logo.svg'
</script>

<template>
  <v-img :src="logo"></v-img>
</template>

I don't really know why do I have to import it though.

Try this one for SVGs maybe. An image is a bit different from an image because of how it's implemented.

@kissu I don't think it's the proper component

Can you provide more details about the problem?

Which browser or browsers are you experiencing this problem on?
Have you tried setting the aspect-ratio property?
Have you tried setting a height?

You may try this:
<v-img :src="require('../assets/logo.svg')" :aspect-ratio="undefined"></v-img>

reference
Edit #1:
Why?
In the classic <img> tag, the browser resolves the relative path at runtime. But with <v-img>, which is a Vuetify component, Vue expects you to pass the image path in a way that the build tool can understand and handle, especially during the bundling process.
When you use require('../assets/logo.svg'), it's similar to importing the image, making sure the bundler processes the SVG correctly and resolves its path, ensuring that it's accessible in the final build.
So, importing or using require() ensures that the asset is properly bundled and available within your Vue component's context.

I'm using Firefox. I tried setting the aspect-ratio, but it doesn't work. I tried setting an height, but it doesn't work

When I tested it on Firefox and Chrome, I was able to successfully display the SVG image. (https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg)
I didn't set any property such as aspect-ratio and height.
My Vuetify version: 3.7.3
My Firefox version: 131.0.3 (aarch64)
You may check your SVG file, your Vuetify and Firefox versions.

This is weird. Did you use the exact same code you provided in the answer?

I wrote like this: 

By specifying the URL it works for me too, but I think the issue happens when you download the image, add it to your project and try to reference it from code

You should be able to see the image with this:  without require i could reproduce your problem but when i try to setting the src of the image with require, everything seems fine.

With Vue 3 and script setup require is not found

Setting height, width of the v-img should works
e.g.
<v-img src="../assets/logo.svg" width="40" height="40" contain></v-img>


It doesn't, at least for me. The image is invisible
